# What is this structure involving a monad and a comonad?

Tags: category-theory, definition, monads

Let $F$ be a monad on some category $\mathsf{C}$ and $G$ be a comonad on the same category. Assume further that they "commute" (see below): $FG \cong GF$. Then, for lack of a better name, one can define "$(F,G)$-bimodules": objects $X$ equipped with an $F$-algebra structure and a $G$-coalgebra structure, both compatible in the sense that the two following maps are equal:
$$(F(X) \to X \to G(X)) = (F(X) \to G(F(X)) \to G(X)).$$

Is this kind of structure studied? What kind of properties does it have?

For the precise meaning of "$F$ and $G$ commute", consider the case where $\mathsf{C}$ is the category of modules over some commutative ring, you have an algebra $A$, a coalgebra $C$, and $F = - \otimes A$ and $G = C \otimes -$ are respectively the "free right $A$-module" and the "cofree left $C$-comodule" functors. Then there is a natural isomorphism $C \otimes (M \otimes A) \cong (C \otimes M) \otimes A$, which is moreover compatible with the monad and comonad structure maps in a way that I don't know how to formalize precisely.

Comment: I believe there is a notion of "distributive law" that applies to this situation, but I do not know the exact definition. A special case shows up in the definition of algebraic weak factorisation system.

Comment: @ZhenLin I know of distributive laws in the context of operads -- you want (say) a "morphism" $P \circ Q \to Q \circ P$ to make $P \circ Q$ into an operad. (Co)operads would certainly be enough for my needs. But this works only if you only have algebraic structures, here I have a mix of algebraic and coalgebraic, so I'm not even sure it's described by a monad (rather a PROP or something?).

Comment: Right. Nonetheless there is a thing called a "mixed distributive law" that allows one to combine a monad and a comonad.

Comment: Interesting. I'll look that up. Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in that [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.4126).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **distributive law** of a monad $(F, \eta, \mu)$ over a comonad $(G, \epsilon, \delta)$ is a natural transformation $\xi : F G \Rightarrow G F$ that satisfies the following equations:

\begin{align}
\xi \bullet \eta G & = G \eta &
\xi \bullet \mu G & = G \mu \bullet \xi F \bullet F \xi \\
\epsilon F \bullet \xi & = F \epsilon &
\delta F \bullet \xi & = G \xi \bullet \xi G \bullet F \delta
\end{align}

For example, in a monoidal category, if $(F, \eta, \mu)$ is the monad induced by a monoid and $(G, \epsilon, \delta)$ is the comonad induced by a comonoid, then the associator defines a distributive law in the sense above.

Now, given a distributive law as above, a **bialgebra** is an object $B$ with an $(F, \eta, \mu)$-action $\alpha : F B \to B$ and a $(G, \epsilon, \delta)$-coaction $\beta : B \to G B$ that satisfies the following equation:

$$\beta \circ \alpha = G \alpha \circ \xi_B \circ F \beta$$

This is studied in more detail in [Power and Watanabe, *[Combining a monad and a comonad](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0304-3975(01)00024-X)*].